# Writing GStreamer plugins using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, gstreamer

I’m trying to write a Gstreamer plugin in Visual Studio 2010.

First, I've downloaded GStreamer package for Windows from
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/.

Then, I’ve added required property sheets and removed the dependency with
the Visual Studio runtime as described in
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows. I successfully built
some examples from Gstreamer Application Development Manual, so I think that SDK is set up correctly.

Now, my other goal is to write my own plugins. The Plugin Writer’s Guide
describes how to construct the boilerplate in Unix/Linux. I've downloaded
gst plugin templates from

git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-tmeplate.git

The guide makes use of make_element utility that creates the boilerplate. I
followed the instructions but this utility doesn't work on Windows.

So I added "gstplugin.c" and "gstplugin.h" to my Visual Studio project as
is. I noticed that “gstplugin.c” doesn’t have main function, what is the
program’s entry point then?

I tried to build the sample plugin as is (I didn't change
templates "gstplugin.c" and "gstplugin.h") and got the following link error:

> msvcrt.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol main

How can I write a Gstreamer plugin in Visual Studio? Also, How can I build
it?  I'm struggling to find good instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to compile my project as dll (instead of application)

This property can be set in Visual Studio under  -> properties -> Configuration Properties -> and then set "Configuration Type" to "Dynamic Library (.dll)".

Comment: Do we need to export any function?